# The PATH solver: changing options

Tags: matlab, optimization

[The PATH solver](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eferris/path.html) is a MATLAB program for solving the linear complementarity problem.

In this solver, users can change default options such as stopping criterion (1e-6); however, I cannot find how to change options in MATLAB.

Could you tell me the way of changing these settings?

Comment: Don't know but that is an option that is best left alone. Tinkering with this is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I think this depends on how to use the solver.